# How to set arguments in Weblogic Admin Server?

Tags: java, environment-variables, weblogic, weblogic12c

Im trying to set arguments in weblogic ->environment->AdminServer->Server Start -> Arguments Arguments : -Denvironment=C://path

And then hit save.

But when I try accessing it like this in my java progam(like its an argument passed to JVM and is in the system env object):

System.getenv("environment") or System.getProperty("environment")

Even printed all properties and the value is not there, is like the weblogic doesnt get updated.

Also from other post in this website it says that I need to reset the weblogic, server, node manager, but I do it and still doesn't work.

Do anybody have steps for correctly setting an argument and use it in java program, or what is the problem?

Also my JAVA_HOME and environment variables are set to the java that weblogic use

Weblogic version : 14.1.1 JAVA Version: Open Java 8(Oracle version)

I did a workaround and set it in the userOverrides.cmd script and it works, but I need to do it through Admin console arguments.